# parallelly run data importing in my case

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing a **Rails v2.3** app. and using **MySQL v5.1** as my DB.

Currently, in my Rails app, I have one **rake task** (invoke a method from Helper) which is used to execute several **.sql** dump file to import data from a **template database** to my `development database`.  For example `execute_dump("fill_all_tables.sql")`.

The **.sql** file looks like:

```
TRUNCTE TABLE cars;
ALTER TABLE DISABLE KEYS
INSERT INTO cars (col1,col2,col3,...) VALUES SELECT (...) FROM template_db.cars WHERE...
ALTER TABLE ENABLE KEYS
OPTIMIZE TABLE
```

Then, I have a **2nd** rake task which will run a script to create a new (3rd) database, also import data from the same **template database** but put data to the new created `3rd database`.

So, two rake tasks(or methods) which both import data from the same **template database** but put to **seperate different databases**. (one to development database while the other to the 3rd database).

**I want to have the above data importing things to be happening parallelly. How can I achieve in Rails?**

### **P.S.**

Both my `development database` and `3rd database` have the same tables created before data importing start.  And my first rake task will do more things after data importing.

Comment: this should like can be solved using replication

Comment: Can you please clarify what the tasks do? "Execute several .sql dump file to import data ..." is not clear to me.

Comment: @ mosch , execute .sql dump file means execute SQL commands, where all commands are in a .sql file. The execute_dump() is a method did this thing(run all SQL statements/commands).

Comment: Could you give an example of what's in these SQL files? Parallelism depends on the commands.  It's tough to parallelize something that requires order.

Comment: So what is keeping you from executing the SQL in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this simply, try using the UNIX shell instead of Ruby. That way, you won't be messing around with fibers, forking and threads. Create two rake tasks that populate your target databases, and put the following code in a file named `db_load.sh`:

```
     #!/bin/sh
     echo "preparing db"
     rake my_project:prepare_database

     echo "starting: copy of template to database 2"
     rake my_project:copy_from_template_database_to_database_2 &

     echo "starting: copy of template to database 3"
     rake my_project:copy_from_template_database_to_database_3 &
```

The ampersands at the end of the last two lines tell the shell to run those tasks in a non-blocking manner. They will run in parallel. (Of course, change the names of the rake tasks to suit your project.)

To run this script, type `chmod +x db_load.sh` to make it executable, then type:

```
     ./db_load.sh
```

Alternatively, you can use backtick notation inside your rake task to accomplish the same thing:

```
    puts "starting: copy of template to database 2"
    `rake my_project:copy_from_template_database_to_database_2 &`

    puts "starting: copy of template to database 3"
    `rake my_project:copy_from_template_database_to_database_3 &`
```

Comment: Thank you rw, but I am afraid the backtick thing in ruby won't return the process after executing a shell command. What I mean is only the first rake task quoted by backtick will be run, then the ruby script will stop, because the process won't return. I would like to have them in ruby script though...so, need a way to workaround still...